# MySQL error :ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'guest'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, access-denied

I have a Linux EC2 instance which has MySQL server installed on it.

I can login with MySQL root with this command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

For some reasons I created a user `guest` using following commands:

```
CREATE USER 'guest'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'guest'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then I exit from root user and try to login with `guest` user:

mysql -u `guest` -p

entered the correct password and got this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'guest'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I even checked out for the `anonymous user` .

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Kindly help. I am not able to connect to MySQL using `guest` user credentials

Comment: Can you do `SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user WHERE User='guest'` ?

Answer (score 2):

**MYSQL AWS LINUX EC2 INSTANCE**
I was trying to access mysql in AWS linux EC2 instance, but was getting the error:- Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. After lot of searching I got the solution which worked for me.
So for mysql community server, the default password is randomly generated whenn you install.

Check **/var/log/mysqld.log file, write vim /var/log/mysqld.log in terminal** and search for the keyword "temporary password"- you will get the password.

Few configurations are required for mysql-  **sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation**

it will ask for password then enter the "temporary password" collected earlier. and in the proceding steps question will be asked over there new password could be easily set. then can proceed with 
**mysql -u root -p.**

Answer (score 0):

try by Run the command

grant all on *.* to 'guest'@'%' identified by 'passpass';
flush privileges;

Thanks